# Re-Arranging the row data in columns

Tags: vba, excel, rows

I have data in excel in following format

```
Resource     2/2/2013   2/3/2013  2/4/2013
  Name1         9          9         9  
  Name2         9          9         9  
  Name3         9          9         9
```

I have to convert the above data into something like this:

```
Resource  Date        Hours
Name1     2/2/2013      9
Name1     2/3/2013      9
Name1     2/4/2013      9
Name2     2/2/2013      9
Name2     2/3/2013      9
Name2     2/4/2013      9
Name3     2/2/2013      9
Name3     2/3/2013      9
Name3     2/4/2013      9
```

Is there any function in `excel` that can do that. I could find only the `row to columns` function that didn't help me as it will just `transpose` the data and not create multiple entries like above.

What could be the best way to do this even through `VBA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim Resources() As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim x As Long

    ReDim Resources(1 To (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1) * (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1), 1 To 3)

    'Change this to the source sheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    'Read data into an array
    For row = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For col = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            x = x + 1
            Resources(x, 1) = Cells(row, 1).Value    ' Get name
            Resources(x, 2) = Cells(1, col).Value    ' Get date
            Resources(x, 3) = Cells(row, col).Value  ' Get value
        Next
    Next

    'Change this to the destination sheet
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    'Write data to sheet
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(Resources), UBound(Resources, 2))).Value = Resources

    'Insert column headers
    Rows(1).Insert
    Range("A1:C1").Value = Array("Resource", "Date", "Value")

    'Set strings to values
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 3))
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

Original:

[image: Original Data]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Only concern is its copying the data in the same sheet and not in the `destination sheet`. It's odd as I am giving correct `sheet names` and yet at the end it just selects the `dest sheet` and all the data is manupulated in the `source sheet` only.

Comment: That should not be happening. It works correctly for me. Have you tried stepping through the code and trying to find the line where it stops working as intended?

Comment: I had copied the code in the sheet. When i used it through module it worked fine. I am going to modify this code a little bit. I am going to use 3 separate 1 dimensional array.but this line `Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(UBound(Resources), 1)).Value = Resources` is giving me only the first element's value for all fields.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if it is possible make without VBA and it seems that it is.
But with some presumption, specifically that the area you are transformin is rectangular.

Then you could use QUOTIENT a MOD function (it would be possible to merge "helper columns C-E" together but for cleaner explanation I show them).

[image]

In A9 I have a value with number of columns (it could be get by another function) - just to be a bit generic.

Then I use INDIRECT() function in this manner:

- cell G9: `=INDIRECT("R"&2+D9&"C1";FALSE)`
- cell H9: `=INDIRECT("R1C"&2+E9;FALSE)`
- cell I9: `=INDIRECT("R"&2+D9&"C"&2+E9;FALSE)`

And then just drag it down.