# Arranging the row data into Columns using VBA in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, rows

I am adapting off of the question: [Re-Arranging the row data in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406370/re-arranging-the-row-data-in-columns?rq=1)

I have Excel data set up as follows;

```
Collection  LatDD   LonDD   Date Location   Method  Specie1 Specie2 Specie3(+-110 species columns in total)     
 ABS1       11.35   -10.3   2003-02-01  A   Bucket      0      1       3       
 ABS2       11.36   -10.4   2003-02-02  B   Stick       2      0       6
```

I would Like This Data to appear like so:

```
Collection  Specie  Count LatDD LonDD    Date       Location  Method
 ABS1        Specie1       11.35  -10.3  2003-02-01     A       Bucket
 ABS1        Specie2   1   11.35  -10.3  2003-02-01     A      Bucket
 ABS1        Specie3   3   11.35  -10.3  2003-02-01     A      Bucket
 ABS2        Specie1   2   11.36  -10.4  2003-02-02     B      Stick
 ABS2        Specie2      -11.36  -10.4  2003-02-02     B       Stick
 ABS2        Specie3   6  -11.36  -10.4  2003-02-02     B       Stick
```

I attempted to adapt Ripsters original VBA code answer but unfortunately i was unable to figure how i would need to change it.  **Could someone please advise me on how to adjust his code to produce the desired output?**

Here is his orginal vba code:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim Resources() As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim x As Long

    ReDim Resources(1 To (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1) * (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1), 1 To 3)

    'Change this to the source sheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    'Read data into an array
    For row = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For col = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            x = x + 1
            Resources(x, 1) = Cells(row, 1).Value    ' Get name
            Resources(x, 2) = Cells(1, col).Value    ' Get date
            Resources(x, 3) = Cells(row, col).Value  ' Get value
        Next
    Next

    'Change this to the destination sheet
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    'Write data to sheet
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(Resources), UBound(Resources, 2))).Value = Resources

    'Insert column headers
    Rows(1).Insert
    Range("A1:C1").Value = Array("Resource", "Date", "Value")

    'Set strings to values
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 3))
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: How about Pivot? or UNPivot?

Comment: I will try that right now

Comment: @Leptonator Unfortunately I'm dealing with  110+ columns, I really need vba

Comment: Power Query (an add-in for 2010, or built-in? in 2013) has an UNpivot function that will work for however many columns you need unpivoted. Example here: http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2013/11/14/un-pivoting-data-in-power-query/

Comment: I have Excel 2013 however the Power Query will not download because it is saying that i do not have the necessary MS excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim x As Long

    h1 = "Sheet1"
    h2 = "Sheet2"
    Sheets(h1).Select
    x = 2
    'Headers Sheet2
    Sheets(h2).Cells(1, 1).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(1, 1)
    Sheets(h2).Cells(1, 2).Value = "Specie"
    Sheets(h2).Cells(1, 3).Value = "Count"
    Sheets(h2).Cells(1, 4).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(1, 2)
    Sheets(h2).Cells(1, 5).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(1, 3)
    Sheets(h2).Cells(1, 6).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(1, 4)
    Sheets(h2).Cells(1, 7).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(1, 5)
    Sheets(h2).Cells(1, 8).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(1, 6)

    For row = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For col = 7 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            Sheets(h2).Cells(x, 1).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(row, 1).Value
            Sheets(h2).Cells(x, 2).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(1, col).Value
            Sheets(h2).Cells(x, 3).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(row, col).Value
            Sheets(h2).Cells(x, 4).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(row, 2).Value
            Sheets(h2).Cells(x, 5).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(row, 3).Value
            Sheets(h2).Cells(x, 6).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(row, 4).Value
            Sheets(h2).Cells(x, 7).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(row, 5).Value
            Sheets(h2).Cells(x, 8).Value = Sheets(h1).Cells(row, 6).Value
            x = x + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Sheet1:
[image]

Sheet2:
[image]

A short versión:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim x As Long

    Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Sh1.Select

    'Headers Sheet2
    Sh2.Cells(1, 1).Value = Sh1.Cells(1, 1)
    Sh2.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Specie"
    Sh2.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Count"
    For i = 4 To 8
        Sh2.Cells(1, i).Value = Sh1.Cells(1, i - 2)
    Next
    x = 2 'Starting row of sheet2.
    For row = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For col = 7 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            Sh2.Cells(x, 1).Value = Sh1.Cells(row, 1).Value
            Sh2.Cells(x, 2).Value = Sh1.Cells(1, col).Value
            Sh2.Cells(x, 3).Value = Sh1.Cells(row, col).Value
            For i = 4 To 8
                Sh2.Cells(x, i).Value = Sh1.Cells(row, i - 2).Value
            Next
            x = x + 1
        Next
    Next
    Sh2.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: The table that appeared when i used that is as follows;       Collection Specie Count Specie Count Specie Count Specie Specie3     
 ABS1 Count 0 Count 0 Count 0 Count 3
 ABS1 Specie Count Count 0 Count 0 Count 6
 ABS1 Specie3      3 Count 0 Count 0 Count 
 ABS1 Count 0 Specie Count Count 0 Count 
 ABS1 Specie Count Specie Count Count 0 Count 
 ABS1 Specie3      6 Specie Count Count 0 Count           Im not sure what went wrong

Comment: @user3726345 Make sure that your data are starting in sheet1 A1 and the format is as you posted. I tried with the format you have posted and I have had no problems.

Comment: It works thank you! I was having trouble with the count column but thanks to you it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

another idea....

Your source data is in "Sheet1", starting at "A1", no empty values neither in Column A, nor in Row 1.

If you run the code, you will get the re-sorted table in "Sheet2" ( I omitted headers, though - too lazy....)

Hope this helps

```html
Sub sort_new()


Dim col_no As Long, row_no As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim arr_DB As Variant, arr_new As Variant
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

ws1.Activate

row_no = ws1.Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).End(xlUp).Row
col_no = ws1.Range(Cells(1, Columns.Count), Cells(1, Columns.Count)).End(xlToLeft).Column

arr_DB = ws1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(row_no, col_no))

ReDim arr_new(1 To (row_no - 1) * (col_no - 6), 1 To 8)

For i = 2 To row_no
    For j = 7 To col_no
        k = k + 1
        arr_new(k, 1) = arr_DB(i, 1) 'Collection
        arr_new(k, 4) = arr_DB(i, 2) 'LatDD
        arr_new(k, 5) = arr_DB(i, 3) 'LonDD
        arr_new(k, 6) = arr_DB(i, 4) 'Date
        arr_new(k, 7) = arr_DB(i, 5) 'Location
        arr_new(k, 8) = arr_DB(i, 6) 'Method
        arr_new(k, 2) = arr_DB(1, j) 'Each Specie(j) Column
        arr_new(k, 3) = arr_DB(i, j) 'Each Specie(j) Column
               
    Next
Next
    
ws2.Activate

ws2.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells((row_no - 1) * (col_no - 6) + 1, 8)) = arr_new

End Sub
```

Comment: No count column is produced.